# Keep Python script listen in background

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I made a really simple python script that listens on a ip + port. I have a network barcode scanner that sends a orderID on that ip + port combination and this script will get the label from a api that sends it to a printer. This is working as it should, I run it on a raspberry.

My only problem is whenever I want to run it as service to be constantly running and listen to the ip for a new scan it only listens to the first scan and prints the right label but the second scan gets the same label.

```
import socket
import urllib.request
import cups
import base64
import json
import re
from PIL import Image

PrintConn = cups.Connection()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.18.208', 51235))

while 1:
        contin = False
        data = s.recv(512)
        print(data)
        if not data: break
        if not data == b'\x02\x18\r\n':
                 contin = True
        barCode = re.findall(r'\d+', data.decode("utf-8"))
        print("https://example.com/api/upsgif/{}".format(''.join(map(str, barCode))))

        if contin:
            try:
                        url = "https://example.com/api/upsgif/{}".format(''.join(map(str, barCode)))
                        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
                        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
                        if not response: break
        upsGif = bytes(response, 'utf-8')
                        if not upsGif: break
                        if upsGif == b'\n': break

                        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
                        print('Error while getting order label')
            else:
                        with open("label.png", "wb") as fh:
                                fh.write(base64.decodebytes(upsGif))

                        img = Image.open('label.png')

                        PrintConn.printFile('Zebra_Printer', '/var/www/label.png', "",{'fit-to-page':'True'})
```

And this is the service I made:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autoinpak keepalive daemon
## make sure we only start the service after network is up
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target

[Service]
## use 'Type=forking' if the service backgrounds itself
## other values are Type=simple (default) and Type=oneshot
Type=forking
## here we can set custom environment variables
ExecStart=/var/www/runClient.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -9 autoinpak
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=infinity
# Useful during debugging; remove it once the service is working
StandardOutput=console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    sudo python3 /var/www/client.py &>/var/log/python/client.log
    wait $!
    sleep 10
done
exit
```

What I expect was that it would work the same as when I run the script from terminal (python3 /var/www/client.py) but instead it uses the same upsgif all the times so every label print is the same as the first scan I do.

Comment: I highly recommend using `supervisord` instead of this `systemd` approach and using `requests` instead of `urllib`